# how to make an Object global in all the code

Tags: php, object, php-5.5, global

What is the most commonly accepted way to make an object accessible everywhere in the code ?

I try to make a little framework for personal projects. Basically i have a Request object, the object needs to be global and accessible in other objects' calls.

I think $GLOBALS['Request'] is one to do so, however this is not very convenient to write.

Comment: The most accepted way is probably not do so but to use a Singleton or similar design pattern instead

Comment: @kingkero that doesn't really help me; since a Singleton can also become global within all the code.

Comment: what I meant to say is that you usually don't have `$request` globally available but `Request::getCurrent()`